# Observation sequences format for HMM in speech recognition

Tags: java, signal-processing, speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to develop a system to seperate garbage from non-garbage in speech recognition. I am using the jahmm implementation of the Hidden Markov Models. I'm confused about the format I should provide the training data to the system as the observation sequence. And what is each state in the HMM composed of? I tried reading the manual but couldnt understand. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused about the format I should provide the training data to the system as the observation sequence.

To understand the format you can just read sources

```
public <O extends Observation> Hmm<O>
    learn(Hmm<O> initialHmm, List<? extends List<? extends O>> sequences)
```

suggests that the input data must be a list of observation sequences. Each observation sequence is a list of observations. If you don't understand what list is, a good introduction into CS can help you

> And what is each state in the HMM composed of?

States of HMM are just elements of mathematical structure. They are not composed of anything. They have a probability distribution associated with them. You can find more details in [HMM tutorial](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.131.2084) which you should better read before you start work on HMM.

The library itself also describes everything well in documentation:

http://jahmm.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/0.6.2/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I understand what you mean, I just don't know how to do it on the signal-processing level, as im a computer science student. If you have any links that can help me understand that, would be great. 
Thanks again

Comment: If you want to get help you need to spend some time to explain what you need. I have no idea what do you mean by "signal processing level" in relation to the original question you asked.

Comment: I mean the speech signal, after getting the MFCCs, do I need to further transform the data before passing it to the HMM for training? Do GMMs have anything to do with the process? Because I dont know what they are.

Comment: You can use MFCC for training or you can add delta features to MFCC for better accuracy. Google can suggest you what delta features are. GMM has nothing to do with the process although you should better study them.

Comment: So its just MFCCs passed as a list of ObservationVector sequences if I got you right?